# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fLocksText'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to a parse an excel file using openpyxl.

I have a working script that is able to parse other existing files with no issues. Now I got this new excel file. It is an xlsx file same as the others. I don't see any issues about it, it's not damage or anything.

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fLocksText'
```

I get this error when I use the load_workbook function to load the excel file. To reiterate, the code works for the existing files so I think the code is ok. But there is this one particular file that won't cooperate. I think this is about the file.

Here's the full error stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "formatRosterFiles.py", line 94, in <module>
    wb = load_workbook(targetSourceFolder + "\\" + fileName, data_only=True)
  File "C:\Users\PMG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages
\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 273, in load_workbook
    for c in find_charts(archive, rel.target):
  File "C:\Users\PMG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages
\openpyxl\chart\reader.py", line 48, in find_charts
    drawing = SpreadsheetDrawing.from_tree(tree)
  File "C:\Users\PMG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages
\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\PMG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages
\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\PMG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages
\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 100, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fLocksText'
```

Here's the line that triggers the error:

```
wb = load_workbook(targetSourceFolder + "\\" + fileName, data_only=True)
```

Comment: Can you show the full error traceback as well as the line of code that causes this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by deleting word art elements. Those were used for headers in the file. Not sure if this could be only reason for this error.

Comment: yes thank you for sharing your answer. for my end, I just copied the whole sheet and pasted as values to a new file. then python is now able to read the file

Comment: For me it was a single image that I had to delete in the file to fix it.